# Bash : Get the bytes at offset for length

Tags: bash, byte, offset, hexdump, xxd

I was wondering how I could retrieve bytes from a files given an offset and a length.

I came to the following line : `hexdump -n 4 -s 0x11C myFile`

I get the following : Not good enough, I don't need the offset.

`000011c 00 00 8c d0`

Second try :

`hexdump -n 4 -s 0x11C -e '"%x\n"' myFile`

I get the following : better but wrong endianness.

`d08c0000`

So how can I do it ? I know I could parse it with sed, but isn't there a «cleaner» solution that that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hexdump -n 4 -s 0x11C -e '4/1 "%x " "\n"' myFile
```

(My version of hexdump does not produce one-byte hex output as in your first example. Did you use some other command option?)

Comment: I'm on OSX so it's a BSD hexdump, maybe that's why. Thanx for your answer, that'll do it ! Actually I don't need the space, so I removed it.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler: Could be. I don't see anything in the docs which would explain that, though. My format should work, though. (I hope.)